# MongoDB User notifications scheme suggestions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I was wondering what is the best scheme for user/notifications kind of scenario like the following:

```
1 | 01-04-2020 | X | John liked your post2 
2 | 01-03-2020 | X | Mike and 9 other persons liked your post1
3 | 01-02-2020 |   | Rose and 2 other persons liked your post1
4 | 01-01-2020 |   | Bernard liked your post1

x = notification has not been read by the user yet
post1 = the same post in all the notifications
```

Let's say I have a Notification collection like:

```
_id: ObjectID
receiver: ObjectID (User)
sender : ObjectID (User)
type: String ("post", "comment", etc...)
typeID: ObjectID (Post, Comment, etc...)
message: String
isRead : Boolean
timestamp: Date
```

A User collection like :

```
_id: ObjectID
username: String
.
.
.
email: String
```

A Post Collection like :

```
_id: ObjectID
postedBy: ObjectID (User)
.
.
.
content: String
```

A Like collection like :

```
_id: ObjectID
type: String ("post", "comment", etc...)
typeID: ObjectID (Post, Comment, etc...)
likedBy: ObjectID (User)
```

- On the 01-01-2020, the user opened his notifications panel. Between the last time he checked his notifications and this date, only 1 person liked his post1.
- On the 01-02-2020, the user opened his  notifications panel. Between the last time he checked his notifications (01-01-2020) and this date, 2 persons liked his post1.
- On the 01-04-2020, the user opened his notifications panel. Between the last time he checked his notifications (01-02-2020) and this date, 9 persons liked his post1 and 1 person liked his post2.

I want the user to be able to see all his previous notifications as well as the notifications he hasn't read yet. If the user has several notifications for the same post (X people liked his post since the last time he checked his notifications), I want to group them as 1 notification (I will mark all of them as read once he read that one grouped notification).

How can I do that?

Please let me know if you need more information or if I am being unclear.

Thanks

---

Edit:

I'm having a hard trying to figure out how to aggregate those notifications. I think I need some kind of read date marker as well to group the notifications that were grouped and read at the same time, but maybe I need another collection to store the grouped notifications?

```
Notification.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    typeID : "$typeID",
                    receiver: "$receiver",
                    isRead: "$isRead"
                    // maybe something with a read date?
                },
                count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        }

])
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess this article at [Mongo University](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary) is a relevant answer to your question.

Use at least two collections: `users` and `notifications` also, you your users `_id` field isn't something like `name` and you'll allow them to be renamed, then it's perfect to have 3-rd collection `likes`, instead making likes as a embedded documents in array, like this:

User's schema:

```
  _id: ObjectID,
  likes: [{
     _id: ObjectID //like_id,
     other: "field"
  }]
```

[image: Pattern]

Notifications:

```
_id: ObjectID
receiver: ObjectID (User)
sender : ObjectID (User)
type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Post", "Comment"] /** Use enum for avaliable values */
    },
typeID: {
    type: ObjectID, /** It's better if every ID field have an index */
    index: true, 
    unique: true
}
message: String
isRead : Boolean
timestamp: { 
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now /** Don't forget about default values, but check my advice below about $timestamps */
}
```

- Not sure that timestamp field is needed for you, as for me, it's
  better to use [`{timestamps: true}`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) option.
- Also, every field with `ObjectID` should be indexed, it you needed
  this fields for `aggregation` framework. It's a perfect performance
  case for `$lookup`

> I want the user to be able to see all his previous notifications as well as the notifications he hasn't read yet.

You needed a `compound` index for this, like `{sender:1, createdAt: -1, isRead: 1}`

> I want to group them as 1 notification (I will mark all of them as read once he read that one grouped notification).

This is a job for `aggregation` framework, via:

```
{
   $match: { query_criteria },

},
{
   $group: { query_group_by $notification.typeID }
}
```

So your schema is fine, it's possible to do that. By the way, to test your own queries, you could use [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/), instead of production DB.

As for the `likes` schema, it's for you to decide, but maybe it's better to have them as an embedded (child) documents, like:

Post

```
_id: ObjectID
postedBy: ObjectID (User)
likes: [{
   /** Likes Sub-schema */
}]
content: String
```

Take a look at [sub-schema pattern](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) in mongoose.

Hope it will helps you!

Comment: Hi AlexZeDim. Thanks you for your answer. I added additional information to my original post to clarify my needs

Comment: @Etanor and I have updated my answer. I guess my answer will be helpful for you. If so, don't forget to up vote answer, or mark is as accepted. SO is based on it. Also, I recommend you to add more relevant tags to your question, like: `mongoose-schema`, `mongoose`, etc. It will really helps you to receive more answers.

Comment: Thank you!
I'm having a hard trying to figure out how to aggregate those notifications. I think I need some kind of read date marker as well to group the notifications that were grouped and read at the same time, but maybe I need another collection to store the grouped notifications?

Notification.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
     typeID : "$typeID",
     receiver: "$receiver",
     isRead: "$isRead"
     // maybe something with a read date?
                },
                count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        }

])